# Root Certificate for all computers in a LAN for Azure’s Point to Site VPN connection

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

In case of Point to Site VPN connection between one to one i.e. Windows Server on Azure and one Windows 10 laptop at premises, it’s okay to create a root certificate of one computer but in case of more than one computer in a LAN in the premise, do I need to create the root certificate of all computers of the LAN and do I need to configure P2S for all computers at Virtual Gateway Network separately?

I don’t think so. Pls clarify.

Comment: Are you using a VPN appliance at both sites to route traffic between sites? If so, then you don't need to touch root CAs on _any_ computer.

Comment: No, I am not using any application. I read some references for P2S VPN connection. In all references, Root certificate of one computer has been created. I just shared a scenario. Pls resolve the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You understanding is right. You just create a root certificate and a client certificate. The root certificate should be upload to Azure. The client certificate can be shared with you pcs. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps

Comment: The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps says, root certificate generated with an enterprise solution (recommended) or generate a self-signed certificate. What about root certificate using an enterprise solution?

Comment: The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps says, each client computer that you connect to a VNet with a Point-to-Site connection must have a client certificate installed. You generate it from the root certificate and install it on each client computer.  You can either generate a unique certificate for each client, or you can use the same certificate for multiple clients. It is confusing. Please clarify it.

Comment: As per the link, “each client computer that you connect to a VNet with a Point-to-Site connection must have a client certificate installed.” If a client certificate is generated from a client computer A, does it mean, the client certificate generated from the client computer A is to be installed in the same client computer A?

Comment: As per the link, “You generate it from the root certificate and install it on each client computer.” If more than one client computers to be connected from the Azure VM using P2S connection, does it mean a client certificate generated from one client computer is to be installed in all client computers?

Comment: @user741975 Your understanding is right . All clients use the same certificate.

Comment: Pls let me know, what about root certificate using an enterprise solution?

Comment: As per my understanding, if Windows Server Domain Controller is setup at Azure and there are some computers in a LAN at site. And if all computers need to join Windows Server Domain Controller, it comes under P2S connection. Am I right?

Comment: If I am right, in such case, do I need to create root certificate in all computers individually and need to update all certificates on Virtual Gateway Network?

Comment: If you use same client certificate, you just need a root certificate. The root certificate is used to ensure if your computer has installed the right client certificate